# IOS8 Clang Error Running Simulator

Tags: xcode, ios8, clang

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction--I've read through the duplicate symbol/clang error questions to no avail. I'm getting the following error when trying to build my project in the simulator (it builds fine on the actual device)

```
duplicate symbol _Command_LowBound in:
PATH/libMixToneLibraryiOS6-All.a(GenHighTDMain_20121211.o)
PATH/libIHRC_ToneDetectLibraryiOS6-all.a(IHRC_ToneDetectFunc_20130306_M1_48k_512_OnOffECC_SelBandNum.o)
duplicate symbol _Command_HighBound in:
PATH/libMixToneLibraryiOS6-All.a(GenHighTDMain_20121211.o)
PATH/libIHRC_ToneDetectLibraryiOS6-all.a(IHRC_ToneDetectFunc_20130306_M1_48k_512_OnOffECC_SelBandNum.o)
duplicate symbol _gECC_OnOff_Flag in:
PATH/libMixToneLibraryiOS6-All.a(GenHighTDMain_20121211.o)
PATH/libIHRC_ToneDetectLibraryiOS6-all.a(IHRC_ToneDetectFunc_20130306_M1_48k_512_OnOffECC_SelBandNum.o)
duplicate symbol _gToneRange in:
PATH/libMixToneLibraryiOS6-All.a(GenHighTDMain_20121211.o)
PATH/libIHRC_ToneDetectLibraryiOS6-all.a(IHRC_ToneDetectFunc_20130306_M1_48k_512_OnOffECC_SelBandNum.o)
ld: 4 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

From reading I know this means there's likely a class showing up twice in my project, but not sure which class or how to narrow it down

As always, any help is appreciated

Comment: The duplicates seem to be in the libraries: `libMixToneLibraryiOS6-All.a` and 
`libIHRC_ToneDetectLibraryiOS6-all.a'

Comment: thanks Zaph, how can I edit these?..Xcode just shows a file icon

Comment: Well, it looks like you have two incompatible libraries. You would need to get the source code for one of them, rename the duplicate function names and re-compile. Or eliminate one of the libraries and find another way to accomplish the lost functions. I don't believe there is a simple solution.